# C# winforms SQLite, локальная база данных

Tags: c#

уважаемые люди помогите пожалуйста разобраться, создал приложение для одного ПК используя SQLite, база данных на DB Browser SQLite, на своем ПК отлично работает( добавляет, удаляет в Базу данных через Datagridview Datatable) теперь я хочу сделать локальное приложение , чтобы пользователи в одной сети могли добавлять и удалять данные через Datagridview , подскажите пожалуйста какие варианты есть ?

Comment: SQLite - однопользовательская БД.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, лучше всего через что реализовать по вашему , через SQL сервер или типа MAMP и т.д ? я хочу чтобы моя приложения работала обновляла данные через локальный сеть когда пользователи вводили данные в DataTable

Answer (score 0):

Между вашим текущим решением и тем что вы хотите - очень большая пропасть.
Но как вариант можно попробовать следующее:

1. Грузить из SQLite данные в DataTable
2. Сериализовать данные из DataTable в Json
3. Отправлять клиенту
4. На стороне клиента десериализовать обратно в DataTable и передавать в Datagridview
5. //do something
6. После внесения изменений сериализовать DataTable в Json и отправлять серверу
7. Десериализовать DataTable на стороне сервера
8. Обновлять данные в DataTable сервера на основании новых данных от DataTable клиента
9. Делать AcceptChanges у DataTable или sqliteAdapter.Update(DataTable)
   PS Если используете несколько связанных таблиц, то лучше использовать DataSet вместо DataTable

Comment: наверное лучше DataGrid на MySql подключу ..... вообще какие еще хорошие варианты есть ?  через SQL сервер лучше реализовать или через MAMP допустим ?, я хочу сделать локально

Comment: Если через сеть, то локально/глобально - никакой разницы нет. И зачем вам MAMP?

Comment: эм...а по другому куда вывести БД ? и как подключится к Базе данным без сервера ? и посоветуйте для этого локальный сервер , если не трудно

Comment: Непонятны вопросы. Что значит вывести БД? Что значит БД без сервера? Что ещё за локальный сервер? Ваше уточнение вопроса само порождает вопрос. Какая у вас цель? Взять данные из БД по сети? Тогда просто берите как самый простой вариант MySQL создавайте в нём БД и манипулируйте данными из своего приложения, всё! Вообще не важно где, как, куда, звучит это всё как гипотетические костыли.